# Get NULL from XML output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below SQL code and it returns NULL if any of column value is NULL. I want it to return something like below.

```
DECLARE @Desc nvarchar(255) = NULL
DECLARE @Test xml = '<Record><Name>Test</Name><Desc>'+@Desc+'</Desc></Record>'

SELECT @Test
```

Output:

```
<Record>
  <Name>Test</Name>
  <Desc>NULL</Desc>
</Record>
```

Comment: SQL is language standard. What kind of DBMS you are using (MySql, MSSql, etc.)

Comment: I am using MSSQL

Comment: 'string' + NULL + 'string' will return NULL. I'm not sure what you're doing and i'm too afraid to ask, but you should probably convert NULL to something, for example by using: `NULLIF(@var, 'NULL')`

Comment: This is something important in XML: do you actually want the string `NULL` in the output or do you want `<Desc>` to have an `xsi:nil="true"` attribute so that consumers know that it's specifically a `null` value?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning This xml data is going to be inserted in destination table. So I don't want to insert string 'NULL' to table, instead I want to insert NULL to table.

Comment: I'm not sure you actually addressed my question. Consider three different ways you might handle null and what outputs you'll get when XML shredding them later on: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qaQDD7v1)

Answer (score 0):

The `COALESCE` [SQL Server function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) will allow you to specify a string value to use when the provided value is a true `NULL`.

The following will generate the XML as given in the question:

```
DECLARE @Desc nvarchar(255) = NULL
DECLARE @Test xml = '<Record>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <Desc>'+COALESCE(@Desc, 'NULL')+'</Desc>
</Record>'
SELECT @Test
```

How this XML is processed to insert data into an underlying table is the other end of the request.

The `NULLIF` [SQL Server function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) will work the other way round, and convert the string 'NULL' into a `NULL` value.

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(20) = N'NULL'
SELECT NULLIF(@var, 'NULL')
/* Prove it's really a NULL not the string 'NULL' */
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(@var, 'NULL'), 'Value is a NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ISNULL` against the string `'NULL'`, but proper XML generation would use `FOR XML` as well, to ensure proper escaping.

```sql
DECLARE @Desc nvarchar(255) = NULL
DECLARE @Test xml = (
    SELECT
      Name = 'Test',
      Desc = ISNULL(@Desc, 'NULL')
    FOR XML PATH('Record'), TYPE
);

SELECT @Test;
```

If however you wanted `xsi:nil` in your XML then just use the `XSINIL` option.

```sql
DECLARE @Desc nvarchar(255) = NULL
DECLARE @Test xml = (
    SELECT
      Name = 'Test',
      Desc = @Desc
    FOR XML PATH('Record'), ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE
);

SELECT @Test;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/VHVOTLYh)